# date checking always returns false

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

i have a custom field expirydate which is made from acf as date picker...with the belowcode i m trying to delete the post tht have expired...for some reason the code  doesn't work.

```
$arg= get_posts(array('post_type' => tokens, 'numberposts' => -1));
foreach ( $arg as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
if (!empty($post))
    {
$expiry=get_field('expiry',$post->ID);
$today=date("d/m/Y");
if ($today>$expiry) {
echo $expiry."expired <br>";
wp_delete_post($postid);
}
else {
echo "not expired"."<br>";
}
}
endforeach;
echo "process completed";
?>
```

the condition `$today>$expiry` is always returning false

Comment: I would convert string to UNIX timestamps and compare them. You can use this function for converting http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing *strings*, not *dates*. So `31/1/2014` is greater than `01/12/2014` because 3 > 1 when *comparing strings*.

To properly compare dates either use a string format that is properly comparable or use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects which are comparable.

```
$expiry = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', get_field('expiry',$post->ID));
$today  = new DateTime();
if ($today > $expiry) {
```

I advise against using `strtotime()` for date comparisons as it does *not* take daylight savings into account.

Comment: great advise, didn't know that.

Comment: it gives me an error...plz not the expirydate saved in the post using acf is of format "dd/mm/yy"

Comment: can u help me with http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/list-all-values-in-select-field/

Comment: @john i tried it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390142/date-comparison-always-returns-false but it doesn't work again...could u plz have a look ...thanx

Comment: for the comparison ($today>$expiry) it now returns true always .