# date comparison always returns false

Tags: php

i am trying to display items that have not expired on the page but its always empty even when the its not expired.plz note the expirydate custom field is created via acf with the saveformat at dd/mm/yy

```
<?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'fooditems', 'numberposts' => -1);
        $todaydate=new DateTime();
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $expirydate=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', get_field('expirydate',$post->ID));
        if ($todaydate <= $expirydate) {
?>
 <div class="index">
                  <h4> <?php echo the_title(); ?> </h4>
                  <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('')?></div>

 </div>

<?php } endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: i think you are having a problem with the variable today date, 

if your'e going to check on the return on the new DateTime() function


it would give you a result like this using a var_dump

 object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2015-02-08 06:45:20' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)


try to compare first the result of $todaydate and $expirydate

Answer (score -1):

ok i found the the solution... it was the `$todaydate=new DateTime();` ...i just changed that to `$todaydate=date('d/m/y')` and it works.